# Denominator identity for Lie superalgebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group, lie-superalgebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a basic classic simple Lie superalgebra.

Fix a maximal isotropic subset $S \subset \Delta$ and choose a set of simple roots $\Pi$ containing $S$. Let $R$ be the Weyl denominator for the corresponding triangular decomposition. The following Weyl denominator identity was suggested by Kac and Wakimoto and is proved [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1181.pdf):

$$R e^{\rho} = \sum_{w \in W^{\#}} sgn(w) w \Big(\frac{e^{\rho}}{\prod_{\beta \in S} (1+e^{-\beta})}\Big)$$

In the denominator identity, we have sum over
the Weyl group $W^{\#}$ which is the Weyl group of the "bigger" irreducible
root system part of the root system of $\mathfrak g_0$. My question is,
what are the white vertices of the Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak g$ whose
associated simple reflections generate $W^{\#}$?.